# Excel Arrow Key is Creating a Formula?

Tags: excel, office-2010, vba

I am having a problem with Excel 2010 that I have never seen before. When I hit the arrow key to move to the next cell, instead of moving to the next cell, it tries to add the next cell.

Example: From Cell A1 if I hit the right arrow key, it does not move to Cell A2, but instead comes up with "+A2" within Cell A1. Has anyone experienced this before?

I'm thinking it's some weird option that can be turned on or off because it happens, no matter which spreadsheet I am in. Thanks in advance for the help.

P.S. - This is NOT the problem where the spreadsheet scrolls when you use the arrow keys. I've already been there and done that. :)

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Your scroll lock is on. This is a bug in excel that surfaces sometimes - particularly in 64 bit office

Comment: No, this answer for another problem.

Comment: It might not be your answer, but I have seen situations where having the scroll lock on and pressing an arrow key causes the behaviour you have described. (adding for anyone looking for solutions in the future)

Answer (score 0):

The solution that everyone suggests is scroll lock key. This did not help me at all.

However, I did just notice that I had the formula builder pane open (I'm on mac, can't verify for win). When I closed it, the problem went away. I can now commit cell values by using the arrow key again!

It seems having the formula builder open puts the cell into formula mode, even if you are not actively using the builder in that cell.